# What happens internally when a file path exceeds approx. 32767 characters in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, internals

In Windows (assume 2000 onwards), a file path can be at most approximately 32767 characters in length. This limitation exists due to the internal handling with [`UNICODE_STRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564879.aspx) in the native API (also on the kernel side, in drivers etc). So far so good. I know the theory behind that part.

The reason for the limit is that the the `Length` and `MaximumLength` members of `UNICODE_STRING` count the number of bytes in the `Buffer`, but are 16 bit unsigned integers themselves.

I also know why the limit is an approximation rather than a set limit. This is mostly due to how your file name (e.g. `\\.\C:\boot.ini`) gets resolved to its native form (e.g. `\??\C:\boot.ini`) and then to something that is prefixed by the *actual* volume device name and then followed by the path relative to that volume, e.g. `\Device\HarddiskVolume2\boot.ini`.

Furthermore from Windows Explorer the known symptom when hitting the ("ANSI") `MAX_PATH` limit is to pretend the file or folder doesn't exist in some versions of Windows (possible this got fixed at some point).

**But what happens at the object manager, I/O manager and file system driver levels respectively** when I call `CreateFile()` with a path that looks like `\\.\C:\...\filename.ext` and the whole path does *not* exceed the limit, but *reaches* it, in my call to `kernel32.dll`'s `CreateFile()` and *then* gets expanded? ...

Neither the SDKs nor the WDKs seem to be particularly chatty about the topic. Or did I look in the wrong sections?

Comment: I also think this is an interesting question, but A) nobody outside of a Microsoft kernel developer could definitively answer it and B) the answer wouldn't be particularly useful anyway.

Comment: @Luke: being a bug hunter I find every little detail not just intriguing but often end up finding them useful in hindsight when tracking down issues. For example when I see particular bug-checks on Windows my experience tells me already where to look first. This will hopefully be another such jigsaw piece :)

Comment: You could try looking at Wine or ReactOS source code for an idea, though there's no guarantee it's exactly the same as what Windows does (but it is likely since they are striving for compatibility).  Or you could just debug it and find out for yourself, though this will probably require kernel debugging.

Comment: This question assumes that path expansion happens in kernel mode; from what I can tell it does not (though I am not a kernel developer and thus not confident enough to post this as an answer).  See [here](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=17#Q5) and [here](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=381) for some explanation of how it works.  It seems to me the expansion happens inside CreateFile(), which fails gracefully if it crosses the 32k UNICODE_STRING length limit; Object Manager et al only parse the names.

Comment: @Luke: I am a kernel developer and I know that parts of the expansion happens in kernel mode. You'll notice in my question that I point out various stages at which I know an expansion will happen. For example in my file system filters I'll commonly see all the symbolic links (object manager lingo, not to be confused with the FS entities) resolved (so instead of `\??\C:` I get to see `\Device\HarddiskVolume2`). But what `CreateFile` does is only to translate the Win32 path to the native one and passing it on (verified through IDA). I.e. `C:` (ANSI/MBCS) or `\\.\C:` (Unicode) to `\??\C:`.

Comment: _"what happens [internally] when I call [a public API with parameters I know the API's internals will fiddle with, causing errors]?"_ - while this is an interesting question, I think the answer is _"That's an implementation detail, bound to change between versions, just be sure to check the return value of the function."_

Comment: This sounds like a job for @RaymondChen.

Comment: Long file names are supported since NTFS 1.x and 32767 (+/-) characters can also be used on Windows NT 3.1 already

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Because I'm lazy, I didn't write a test program but tested it using the excellent [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/) which handles things like long paths (longer than `MAX_PATH`) or special filenames (`con`, `prn` etc) just fine.

I made a string of exactly 255 characters ("12345678901234...012345") and started creating nested directories. Luckily, Far's "Make Directory" function takes a slash-separated string to mean "create nested directories" so I was able to do it in just a few steps by preparing a string in the internal editor with some copy&paste.

The longest path I was able to create was **32739** characters long, counting from "C:\" (i.e. it does not include "\\?\" added by Far). The error that I get when trying to create a directory or file with just one additional character is "**The filename or extension is too long.**". If I try to enter that directory, I get the same error.

**EDIT**: spent some time in the debugger and here's what happens on the Win32 API level:

1. I try to create a file with one character above the limit
2. Far calls `CreateFileW` with the string "\\?\C:\123[...]012345"
   which is **32744** wide characters long (not counting the terminating zero).
3. `CreateFileW` does some extra checks, converts the null-terminated string to `UNICODE_STRING` (Length=65488, MaximumLength=65490) and prepares an `OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` struct.
4. `CreateFileW` then calls [`NtCreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432380) in `ntdll.dll`, which is just a wrapper around `syscall` instruction.
5. `NtCreateFile` returns **0xC0000106** (`STATUS_NAME_TOO_LONG`).
6. That status value is then converted (using `RtlNtStatusToDosError`) to the Win32 error 206 (`ERROR_FILENAME_EXCED_RANGE`).

<strike>I did not bother checking what happens in the kernel, but I guess I could have a look at that too</strike>.

**EDIT2**: I ran [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657.aspx) and found that on my system `C:` is a symlink to `\Device\HarddiskVolume1`. This string is **23 characters** long. If we replace the `\C:` in the string passed to `NtCreateFile` with it, we get 32744 - 3 + 23 = **32764** characters. Together with the terminating zero, this requires 65530 bytes. Still short of the limit (0xFFFF=65535) so I guess there's something extra being added, like a session or namespace name.

**EDIT3**: after going through the kernel:

1. `NtCreateFile` calls `IopCreateFile`
2. `IopCreateFile` calls `ObOpenObjectByName`
3. `ObOpenObjectByName` calls `ObpLookupObjectName`
4. `ObpLookupObjectName` checks for `ObpDosDevicesShortNamePrefix` (`"\??\"`) -> success
5. it skips the prefix and splits the remaining part into `"C:"` and `"\1234..."`
6. it resolves the `"C:"` with a call to `ObpLookupDirectoryEntry`
7. it then calls **`ObpParseSymbolicLink`** passing to it the looked-up directory entry (`_OBJECT_SYMBOLIC_LINK` with `LinkTarget` == `"\Device\HarddiskVolume1"` and `DosDeviceDriveIndex` == 3) and the remaining part of the name.
8. It then does something like this (faithfully [reproduced by ReactOS](http://doxygen.reactos.org/da/d0a/ob_8h_ab927f63c0efdf3e4ba6142ec45d0aadf.html)):

   ```
   TargetPath = &SymlinkObject->LinkTarget;
   TempLength = TargetPath->Length;
   TotalLength = TempLength + RemainingName->Length;
   if (LengthUsed > 0xFFF0)
       return STATUS_NAME_TOO_LONG;
   ```

   In our case, 46 + 65476 = 65522 (0xfff2) which is just above the limit.

   So there, mystery solved (I hope!).

P.S. everything tested under Windows 7 x64 SP1.

Comment: "C: is a symlink to \Device\HarddiskVolume1", hah, so Windows is a Unix in disguise.

Comment: @SiyuanRen: not quite. Or are you implying that a single-root namespace is something that only Unix has ever invented (and invented first)?

Comment: @SiyuanRen: in particular it should be noted that the defining part in Unix is not so much the single root, but the "everything is a file" paradigm. However, that does not apply to NT.